# Remove the "Administrator:" text from the title when you run cmd.exe as an administrator

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, command-line

In Windows, when I run cmd.exe as an administrator, the title of the Window is "Administrator: CMD". Is there any way I change it back to just "CMD"?

Comment: This exact question has been asked on SF. http://serverfault.com/questions/35561/how-to-remove-administrator-from-the-command-promt-title